# web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction takes too long time, which strategy?

Tags: pending-transactions

Until now, I used rinkeby test network, where things are a lot faster, i discovered.

I was doing this

```
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction);
    console.log(receipt.transactionHash);
    console.log(receipt.gasUsed);
```

So I can send signed transaction, ans simply wait to get the tx hash.

I tried on main net and, to keep gas cost lower, it takes also 15 minutes per transaction to be mined.

My caller script goes in timeout a lot earlier than 15 minutes.

Is there a way to simply 'fire' the sending but obtaining the transactionHash anyway without keep listening for a long time?

Have you other strategies to suggest me?

I recently discovered contract events. So i'm firing an event when the called function ends. But is this a good way to fight this problem?

Web3Js version is set as: `"web3": "^1.2.6",`

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: Actually I'm using 1.2.6